# bib file issues

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Currently this is the content of my bib file:

```
@Article{RMPM,
  author =       "B. Wang, M.A Hicks, P.J. Vardon",
  title =        "Slope failure analysis using the random material point method",
  volume =       "6",
  number =       "2"
  pages =        "113-118",
  year =         "2016",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1680/jgele.16.00019"
} 

@Article{RFEM,
  author =       "M.A Hicks, W.A. Spencer",
  title =        "Influence of heterogeneity on the reliability and failure of a long 3D slope",
  volume =       "37",
  number =       "7-8"
  pages =        "948-955",
  year =         "2010"
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1680/jgele.16.00019"
}
```

I would like this to give me a clean set of journal references with numbered indices similar to those shown [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles). However what I'm getting is something along the lines of[image]

Firstly, the "References" caption is way too high up above the bibliography.

Secondly, the references are not numbered. When I cite them the citation appears as the full name of the authors+the date which is not what I'm looking for. I would prefer a numbered citation instead...

Thirdly, the journal-related fields are not showing in my list of references. As can be seen from the bib file I am providing a date, page numbers and a DOI which do not appear in the bibliography itself.

The code from my tex file is shown below:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Brief literature review}
\shorttitle{APA style}

\author{Name}
\affiliation{affiliation}

\abstract{This is a brief literature review for both documents provided by }

\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{Author One}

\begin{document}
\cite{RMPM,RFEM}

\bibliography{Ref}

\end{document}
```

Where `Ref.bib` is the `bib` file.

How can I get Texmaker to give me numbered references and fix the journal entry problems as explained above?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Allright I'll do that and edit the question.

Comment: Here you can find different bibliography styles: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibtex_bibliography_styles also with numbered citation.

Comment: Use `and`  not a comma to separate authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, the `apacite` bibliography style is meant to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs, *not* numeric citation call-outs. If you must create numeric citation call-outs, don't use the `apacite` bibliography style. That said, since you're using the `apa6` document class, I can't see why you would want to choose anything but authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Second, the two bib entries you've posted contain several egregious errors.

- Use the keyword `and` to separate authors. *Do not use commas for this purpose.*
- Each field must be terminated by a comma. Currently, the first entry is missing one comma field terminator, while the second entry is missing two [2!] comma field terminators.
- For entries of type `@article`, the field `journal` is *required*. However, this information is missing in both entries.

Here's a suggestion for a partial edit.

```
@Article{RMPM,
  author =       "B. Wang and M. A. Hicks and P. J. Vardon",
  title =        "Slope failure analysis using the random material point method",
  journal =      "aaa bbb ccc",
  volume =       "6",
  number =       "2",
  pages =        "113-118",
  year =         "2016",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1680/jgele.16.00019"
} 

@Article{RFEM,
  author =       "M. A. Hicks and W. A. Spencer",
  title =        "Influence of heterogeneity on the reliability and failure of a long {3D} slope",
  journal =      "aaa bbb ccc",
  volume =       "37",
  number =       "7-8",
  pages =        "948-955",
  year =         "2010",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1680/jgele.16.00019"
}
```

---

Here's a full MWE. Observe that, in addition to implementing the suggestions given above, (a) I've changed `-` to `--` in the `pages` and `number` fields and (b) the `url` package is loaded explicitly, with the option `hyphens`. Obviously, you'll need to supply the correct journal names.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Ref.bib}
@Article{RMPM,
  author =       "B. Wang and M. A. Hicks and P. J. Vardon",
  title =        "Slope failure analysis using the random material point method",
  journal =      "abc def ghi",
  volume =       "6",
  number =       "2",
  pages =        "113--118",
  year =         "2016",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1680/jgele.16.00019"
} 

@Article{RFEM,
  author =       "M. A. Hicks and W. A. Spencer",
  title =        "Influence of heterogeneity on the reliability and failure of a long {3D} slope",
  journal =      "jkl mno pqr",
  volume =       "37",
  number =       "7--8",
  pages =        "948--955",
  year =         "2010",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1680/jgele.16.00019"
} 
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\title{Brief literature review}
\shorttitle{APA style}

\author{Name}
\affiliation{Affiliation}

\abstract{This is a brief literature review for 
both documents provided by \dots}

\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{Author One}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1] % filler text

As argued by \citeA{RMPM} and \citeA{RFEM}, \dots

\bibliography{Ref}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and helping me pick out these errors. However 2 problems persist. The "References" caption is still way up there, looking like regular text with excessive spacing and not like a caption at all. The years of publication still do not appear.  Furthermore removing `apacite` throws me into a world of hurt. I'd like to get rid of it, but how to do so as smoothly as possible?

Comment: @user32882 I've posted a full MWE (minimum working example). Incidentally, if you don't use the `apacite` package and bibliography style, you need to specify an alternative. Simply removing the `apacite` option from the `\documentclass` directive has no chance of working.

Comment: I guess not. Perhaps I need to be using a different `\documentclass`? I am looking to do something like this: ctp.itp.ac.cn/EN/article/downloadArticleFile.do?attachType=PDF&id=11180

Comment: @user32882 The linked document definitely uses authoryear-style rather than numeric citation call-outs.

Comment: sorry my bad just modified the comment, this one uses numeric style call outs

Comment: @user32882 - It looks like you're preparing to submit a paper to a journal. If so, do consult the journal's instructions for the document class that should be used.

Comment: I am not preparing to submit a paper. I might need to in the future using a similar format to the one in the link. This is a pure self-learning exercise for me... there are no instructions to consult...

Comment: @user32882 - If this is a "pure self-learning exercise" and no special formatting requirements are present, I would definitely not use the `apa6` document class. I'd probably just go with the `article` document class, the `natbib` citation management package (with the option `numbers`, to create numeric-style citation call-outs,, and the `plainnat` bibliography style.